# How can I add button icons to custom keyboard iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I am creating custom keyboard for ios 8. Creating keyboard buttons like this

```
    UIButton *aBtn = [ UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom ];

    [aBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(x, 30, btnWidth, btnHeight)];

    [aBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"A"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [aBtn setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aBtn setTitleColor:[ UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aBtn setTitleColor:[ UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [aBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:aBtn];
```

My problem is that the image is not set to button. How can I solve this?

Do I need any special steps to be able to add images to Xcode for custom keyboards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably didn't add the image to your keyboard target.

Check your keyboard target > Build Phases > Copy bundle resources to make sure that the image is there. Drag it there if it isn't.

Note that I am talking about the keyboard target, not the host app. That could be the confusion here.

Answer (score 3):

## You can add image on custom keyboard like below steps.

## 1. Add images in your xcode project

## 2. Add images in keyboard bundle resources. check below image

[image]

## 3. Set image with background on button. check below image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a new "Assets Catalog" in your custom keyboard folder ( Where "KeyboardViewController.swift" file is located.

[image]

Then add your image in "Assets Catalog" folder and use the following code.

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system) as UIButton     
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
if let image  = UIImage(named: "image_name") { // no need to use ".png format"
    button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
}
button.backgroundColor = .red // to show button position
view.addSubview(button)
```